# Saving layout template with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, layouts

I am searching for a way to save a layout as .qpt file, is that possible with PyQGIS and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use the following to define the layout and use the [QgsLayout::saveAsTemplate()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayout.html#a20f1d0e8ccc8612a5a7f396486a3c04a) method:

```
layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('layoutName')
layout.saveAsTemplate('path/to/layout.qpt', QgsReadWriteContext())
```